# View the LoginViewController everytime

Tags: swift, xcode, authentication

I have HomeViewController with Modal Segue to LoginViewController. I login and everything is OK. My HomeViewController has a button to nextViewController. But when I come back from nextViewController to HomeViewController my program view LoginViewController.

How I can view Login only one time?

Comment: Share your code snippet for more details

Comment: I think that isn't needed. I dont want public it.

Comment: I do think this *is* needed as well. Don't worry, no one is going to steal your code.

Answer (score 0):

Cross Check two things.

**1) Check segue is not enabled with the back button.**

**2) Make sure you not poping two times from your nextViewController.**

Comment: Can you explain it with more details?